# Simplify Move and Maximise screen using Selenium (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am running my selenium tests using a ruby Framework having recently joined a new company. As I am working on 3 screens I have added in a browser step to move the browser window to my left most screen before maximising using

```
@driver.manage.window.move_to(-1800, 1500)
@driver.manage.window.maximize
```

My question very simply is, having never used Ruby before, is there a way to refactor these 2 lines into 1 I have tried various ways but always get an error.

Comment: Why do you want to refactor it into one line if I may ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible in this place because both are returning `string` object so you can't cascade the calling like

```
@driver.manage.window.move_to(-1800, 1500).maximize
```

But If it's very important for you, then I will tell you a way to do this, open the window.rb file where you can return the self from move_to function as shown below

```
  def move_to(x, y)
    @bridge.reposition_window Integer(x), Integer(y)
    self
  end
```

And then you can make a call like this

```
@driver.manage.window.move_to(-1800, 1500).maximize
```

Comment: @RichardC Welcome!